# Adding custom section to web.config in ASP.NET 4

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I've spent half of a day trying to understand why the following fails.

I can add section anywhere but never got it working like that ():

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>

       <mysection />

       <system.web>
       <compilation debug="false" batch="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
       </system.web>
       <system.webServer>
         <handlers>
         </handlers>
       </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

I think the error related to .NET 4, because when you put section without pre-configuration in applicationHost.config it shows error with gray border saying that config is incorrect. That is what I expect. Then I add section definition and everything seems to work I can edit config from console - this means it is parsed correctly now.

But when I try to reach Application, it gives:

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section mysection

with a piece of config on yellow background.

Or do I need to write a module to consume that settings ? At the moment I do not have any, just a text in config.

Answer (score 0):

following links will help you understand  for this.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32628/ASP-NET-Custom-Web-Configuration-Section

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020133931/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/032807-1.aspx

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is not clear to me, is approach with adding schema definition to applicationHost.config is OLD and not sufficient for .NET 4 apps ?

Comment: so what kind of functionality you want for this?

Answer (score 0):

Old topic but these links are very helpfull:

http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/extending-iis-configuration/configuration-extensibility

http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/extending-iis-configuration/extending-iis-schema-and-accessing-the-custom-sections-using-mwa

Edit (05/25/2016) :
The Details of how to store custom information in **applicationHost.config** file ... I hope this helps !

Note : These settings wont be visible on IIS Manager. There is a way to do that but thats beyond the scope of this response.

Requirement:
Need to extend the system.applicationHost/sites section of  **applicationHost.config** file to allow a **siteowner** attribute at the site level. (IIS Does not allow us to do this by default). Nor can you manually edit the **applicationHost.config** file and add custom tags/attributes.

Steps:

1. Create a custom schema ( xml ) file under %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\schema\ . File name: siteExtension_schema.xml
2. Include the custom elements that you want to eventually save in the applicationHost.config in that xml and save it with a appropriate name. The crucial thing to keep in mind is the sectionSchema tag.So when extending the schema of an existing section, simply create a  element and set the name attribute to be the same as an existing section. In the schema file (see below), we have defined a  with a name of "system.applicationHost/sites" - this is the same as the sectionSchema name in the default IIS_Schema.xml file in the Schema directory. So in essence you are instructing IIS to add these

```html
<!-- Contents of %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\schema\siteExtension_schema.xml -->
  <configSchema>
    <sectionSchema name="system.applicationHost/sites">
      <collection addElement="site">
        <attribute name="owner" type="string" />
        <attribute name="ownerEmail" type="string" />
      </collection>
    </sectionSchema>
  </configSchema>
```

3. Test the modifications by adding values for the "owner" and "ownerEmail" attributes that we included in step 2 above and then check the configuration file (applicationHost.config) to see the changes. Simply run the following command (must be elevated as Administrator) from the command line (uses appcmd ) to do so:

`C:\> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set site "Default Web Site" /owner:"John Contoso" /ownerEmail:"john@contoso.com"`

4. To see if the configuration was applied, run the following command and check the output:

`C:\> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list site "Default Web Site" /config`

```html
<system.applicationHost> 
<sites> 
...
    <site name="Default Web Site" id="1" siteOwner="John Contoso" siteOwnerEmail="john@contoso.com">
    ...
    ...
    </site> 
</sites> 
</system.applicationHost>
```

5. To Read and Write your settings programmatically thru C# :

   ```
   //this Will work with the ServerManager.OpenRemote("MyRemoteHostname") method also

   using(var mgr = new ServerManager()) 
   {
   //Read
   Console.WriteLine(mgr.Sites["Default Web  Site"].Attributes["owner"].Value      ); //Prints "John Contoso"

   //Write
   mgr.Sites["Default Web Site"].Attributes["owner"].Value = "New Owner";// Sets new value
   mgr.CommitChanges(); // commits the changes to applicationHost.Config
   }
   ```